# How Can I Put An Item Next to Each Other?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to put a label to the right of an image in a stacklayout, using XAML and Xamarin, I Just Want to put it to the right, and the content down of it should still showing in vertical, like the normal stacklayout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place the image and label into a grid, assigning a column to each, that is within the StackLayout and the rest of the elements outside of the grid.

#### Example:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Source="xamarin_logo.png" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Black" />
        <Label Text="Xamarin Logo" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </Grid>
    <Label Text="Xamarin A" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <Label Text="Xamarin B" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    <Label Text="Xamarin C" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
</StackLayout>
```

#### Output:

[image]

re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid